# Drawing line between intersection of two shapes

Tags: java, graphics

I am playing around with graphics, specifically the intersection and union of primitive shapes.

Given the following:

```
Elipse2D e1 = new Elipse2D.Double(120, 80, 80, 80);
Elipse2D e2 = new Elipse2D.Double(180, 80, 80, 80);

Area a1 = new Area(e1);
a1.add(new Area(e2));

gfx.draw(a1); // gfx is a Graphics2D object
```

This gives a very nice shape that looks like a 1st-person eye-view from binoculars in some 90's action movie.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to draw a line between the two intersection points so that is looks almost like two cells busy dividing.  After doing this with two circles, is this possible with multiple circles, perhaps?

I know this can be done by finding the intersection points between the two circles and drawing the lines manually, however, I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the parameterization of these `Ellipse2D`, the equations can be written as:

```
x(r) = X + W (cos(r) + 1)/2
y(r) = Y + H (sin(r) + 1)/2

x(s) = X + W' (cos(s) + 1)/2
y(s) = Y + H  (sin(s) + 1)/2
```

The `y` equations allow to conclude that the angles `r` and `s` have the same sine and are supplementary (equal angles would not satisfy the `x` equations), so that `cos(s)=-cos(r)`.

After elimination, we have `(W'+W) cos(r) = W'-W`. In the given case, `cos(r)=1/5` and `r=78.463°`.

Comment: Yip... I went for this after finding that the wheel I am looking for is not part of the core libraries.